# Where to see a LIST of all fanpages I am liking (''Like'' button)?

Tags: facebook

On the left hand-side menu, there is a part of menu called Groups and there are clearly and visibly listed all groups I have joined. Would like to know, in the similar way, where could I see a list of ALL, without an exception, fanpages that I am liking? So where do I see a list of ALL fanpages where I clicked button Like in the past? Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you don't seem to want to use the facebook-API to do this.

Comment: using API won't tell me whether or not others (people i added as a friend or friends' friends) see which fanpages I ''like'' (clicking Like button in the past).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be a programming question. For Facebook end user support/feature requests, please refer to their Help section.